# How to solve simple programming problem with strange math question?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Here is the question:

> A cookie recipe calls for the following ingredients:
>
> - 1.5 cups of sugar
> - 1 cup of butter
> - 2.75 cups of flour
>
> The recipe produces 48 cookies with this amount of the ingredients.
>   Write a program   that asks the user how many cookies he or she wants to
>   make, and then displays the number of cups of each ingredient needed
>   for the specified number of cookies.

I already saw the answer, and it only confused me more. I need someone to explain to me how we go about figuring out how many cups of sugar is needed if, for example, the user wants to bake 50 cookies.

*EDIT: I'm mainly interested in the thought process used to solve the **math** portion of this problem.*

Comment: How much of each ingredient do you need for one cookie?

Comment: @BenLongo 0.0375 cups of sugar ... Then multiply this by the number of cookies the user needs ..... wow, I feel stupid. I looked at this problem with all 3 ingredients combined together, confusing the heck out of me. Thanks  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, scale down the various ingredient requirements from a 48-cookie batch size to an individual cookie size. This is done by dividing your three amounts {1.5, 1, 2.75} by 48, giving {1/32, 1/48, 11/192}. Then all one has to do is multiply the required cookie batch size by each of these individual amounts. At least that is how I'd do it.